# which datatype is r_Cntr in the perl code below?

Tags: perl

```
my $r_Cntr = {} 
$r_Cntr->{'behaviour'} = $RESET
```

After setting this value r_Cntr is pushed to an array.

Comment: If you'd use `;`, the code would compile and `$r_Cntr` would be a hash ref.

Comment: `$r_Cntr` is a scalar (as indicated by the `$`). Its value is a reference to a hash (as you can see from `$r_Cntr = {}`.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> my $r_Cntr = {};
> ```

`$r_Cntr` is a scalar. It contains a reference to a hash. After running this line of code, the referenced hash is empty.

> ```
> $r_Cntr->{'behaviour'} = $RESET
> ```

After running this line of code, the referenced hash contains a single key ('behaviour') and the associated value is whatever in in `$RESET`.

Running it through [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) might be useful.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $RESET = 'Some random text';

my $r_Cntr = {};
$r_Cntr->{'behaviour'} = $RESET; 

print Dumper $r_Cntr;
```

Which produces the following output:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'behaviour' => 'Some random text'
};
```